AutoIt library not clicking dropdown of windows print pop-up using robot framework
I am trying to select the Save as PDF option fron the print pop-up of windows. For which I have used AutoItLibrary along with Robot Framework. My code is as below but I am unable to click the Destination dropdown of the print pop-up. Please help me what can be wrong here. Is it Intermediate D3D Window value which is wrong? I got this Class value from the AutoIt v3 window info tool. Please guide also if any alternate solution.
*** Settings ***
Library           AutoItLibrary
Library           AutoItLibrary

print_try
    open browser    https://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/print-button.html    browser=Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    click element    //button[.='Print this page']
    Sleep    30s
    Win Wait Active    Creating a Print Button
    Win Activate    Creating a Print Button
    Control Focus    Creating a Print Button    ${EMPTY}    Intermediate D3D Window
    Control Click    Creating a Print Button    ${EMPTY}    Intermediate D3D Window    Left
    Sleep    10s


Please note the used URL is just for example, i do not own this URL.

@KJ shown above is just an example. In real scenario I don't have to print a HTML, it's a complex UI which I need to print. Hence, I cannot use HTML2PDF

Hey @Anna, I have added the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78575504/17041240. I hope that helps.

Sorry if I am not understanding your project, from what I can see, if the automation is going to be run on the same screen resolution then using mouse click might be the best way to go.
If you are simply wanting to automate the saving as PDF you can use:
mouseClick("left",posX,posY)
